# как вытащить информацию из firebase в соседние activity?

Tags: java, android

вывожу информацию из firebase в ListView...
Хочу сделать следующее, при нажатии на какой либо Item в ListView, открывалось activity с более детальной информации об этом Item из ListView...

Смысл заключается в том, что он вытаскивает последнюю запись из базы, а как открывать ту которую я хочу при нажатии любого Item ????

Достаю так:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference uidRef1 = rootRef1.child("Markers").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        uidRef1.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                Log.d(TAG, "Adding location for '" + key + "'");
                Double latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                Double longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
            }
            
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                String key1 = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                Log.d(TAG, "Location for '" + key1 + "' was updated.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                Log.d(TAG, "Location for '" + key + "' was removed.");
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Priority for " + dataSnapshot.getKey() + " was changed.");
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "markerUpdateListener:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });

    }
```

и в Listview передаю информацию в Activity:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
            intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);

            startActivity(intent);

        }});
```

Comment: Получите сначала объект из listview и его передавайте. Object listItem = listview.getItemAtPosition(position);

Comment: спасибо!! А как из новой активити в которой лежит подробная информация об определенным item ее удалить? ато он удаляет все базу сразу DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("marker");
        myRef.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).removeValue();